# Adding counter to bubblesort function

Tags: c++, algorithm, bubble-sort

I need to calculate the total number of swapping process and sorting running time for my bubble sort function. For running time, I was successful. But for the total number of swapping processes, I couldn't really understand what to do. I thought of initializing "count" and then tried to call it into the main function. That was a failure.

This if my bubble sort function:

```
void bubbleSort(T patient[], int size)
{
  bool noChange = true; // stop when a pass causes no change
    for(int i = size; i > 0; i--)
  {
    noChange = true;
    for(int j = 1; j < i; j++)
    {
      if(patient[j] < patient[j - 1])
      {
        swap(patient[j], patient[j-1]);
        count = count + 1;
        noChange = false;
      } // end if
    } // end for(j)
    if (noChange)
      return; // sorted--no need to continue
  } // end for(i)
}
```

"count" seems to show no value when called into the main function. Any tips on what I should try so that I could get the total number of swapping process in this?

EDIT 3:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 5;
template <class T>
void printArray(T ar[], int sz);
template <class T>
int bubbleSort(T ar[], int sz);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main Function Implementation
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main() {
    int numOfData = 50000;
    string line, temp;
    ofstream resultFile;
    string patient[numOfData];
    ifstream dataFile("shufflePatient.txt");
    int times,i,count;

    cout << "Program to shuffle data" << endl << endl;
    cout << "This program will calculate swapping processes and running time.";


    /*Storing data*/
    cout << "Reading data in process.." << endl;
    if (dataFile.is_open()) {
        i=-1;
        while (dataFile.good()) {
            getline (dataFile, line);
            if (i>=0) patient[i] = line;
            i++;
        }
        dataFile.close();
    }



    double start_s=clock();
    bubbleSort(patient,SIZE);
    double stop_s=clock();


    cout << "time: " << (stop_s-start_s)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl;
    count = bubbleSort(patient,SIZE) ;
    cout << "swapping process : " << count ;

    cin.get(); // hold window open

    /*Writing to file*/
    cout << "Writing to file.." << endl;
    resultFile.open ("test.txt");
    for (int i=0 ; i<numOfData ; i++) {
        resultFile << patient[i] << "\n";
    }
    resultFile.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}





//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// prints array of size size
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T>
void printArray(T patient[], int size)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cout << patient[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;
}






//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// sorts array of size size by Bubble Sort method
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T>
int bubbleSort(T patient[], int size) //returning an int
{
   int count = 0; //initializing count
   bool noChange = true;
    for(int i = size; i > 0; i--)
  {
    noChange = true;
    for(int j = 1; j < i; j++)
    {
      if(patient[j] < patient[j - 1])
      {
        swap(patient[j], patient[j-1]);
        count = count + 1;
        noChange = false;
      }
    }
    if (noChange)
      return count; // returning count
  }
  return count; // returning count
}
```

This is my updated code. Count value returns to 0. I don't know if the code I've used is right or wrong (where i call the return value of count). Any thoughts?

PS
Also, after changing my functions from void to int, for some reason my code stops sorting the data alphabetically when its written into the "text" file. Whats up with this?

Comment: Where did you initialize `count`?

Comment: What does it mean to show no value? Please be specific. If your expected output does not match actual output, show both.

Comment: You're not using the return value of bubbleSort() - of course it's not displaying anything.

Comment: Also, the error is presumably because you're defining `void bubbleSort(T ar[], int sz);` at the top, but declaring `int bubbleSort(T patient[], int size)` at the bottom.   In future, please tell us what the error is, rather than just saying "It gave an error"

Comment: Yea I'm really sorry about that. Fixing this issue you've mentioned causes my code to build successfully. But, I don't know how to call "count" from the "function" into  "main".

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the return value from the function, why don't you make the function return `int` - and return the count of number of swaps:

```
int bubbleSort(T patient[], int size) //returning an int
{
   int count = 0; //initializing count
   bool noChange = true; 
    for(int i = size; i > 0; i--)
  {
    noChange = true;
    for(int j = 1; j < i; j++)
    {
      if(patient[j] < patient[j - 1])
      {
        swap(patient[j], patient[j-1]);
        count = count + 1;
        noChange = false;
      } 
    } 
    if (noChange)
      return count; // returning count
  } 
  return count; // returning count
}
```

---

**PS** 

The problem in the original code could be where you declared or initialized `count` (which is not shown in the code snap).

Also, using *local variable* is usually a better practice than using *global* ones.

Comment: would really like an update on how to handle the code. please check my edited version.

Comment: the code wasn't sorting alphabetically anymore. also, i was getting a wrong value of count (maybe because of wrong coding). i then used a global "count" variable, changed int back to void, and everything is working fine now.